# A primary key in ORACLE 11g became nullable

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table named 'ROUTE'. What "desc ROUTE" does is as follow:

```
Name                 Null Type           
-------------------- ---- -------------- 
ROUTE_GUID                RAW(16 BYTE)   
LINE_GUID                 RAW(16 BYTE)   
EVENT_GUID                RAW(16 BYTE)   
DESCRIPTION               VARCHAR2(254)
```

Where ROUTE_GUID IS PK. When I tried altering the table, it showed "ORA-01442: column to be modified to NOT NULL is already NOT NULL". The real problem is that a .NET application has to use this table but it cannot unless a non-nullable column is found. There are also many database views associated with this table so that these view cannot be retrieved by .NET as well. Anyone got the same problem?

Comment: The message tells you that you are trying to set `not null` on a column that is already `not null`. Why do you think there is a `null` column to begin with?

Comment: Because apart from ORA01442 when I alter this table, Everywhere else (sqlplus, .NET) sees this column as null.

Comment: Are you using some ORM that shows the column as `Nullable`? Can you change it to Not nullable (which will only change what the ORM sees)?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue in Oracle 12g r 2.  The `desc MY_TABLE` did not show the `NOT NULL` for a column that did have a `NOT NULL` constraint.  Querying the `DBA_TAB_COLS` table for the `NULLABLE` column did not show it either.  If I queried the `DBA_CONS_COLUMNS` and
`DBA_CONSTRAINTS` it did show up!  The web site https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-ora-01442-column-to-be-modified-to-not-null-is-already-not-null/ almost helps; it showed the case where the constraint was in DISABLED status; my situation, the status was ENABLED.  I just did a disable followed by an enable, and it worked; the NOT NULL is displayed now.

Code to display NOT NULL constraint name:

```
select a.constraint_name, b.status
from dba_cons_columns a
inner join dba_constraints b
on a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
where a.table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
and a.owner = 'SCOTT' and a.owner=b.owner
and a.column_name = 'USER_NAME' 
and b.constraint_type = 'C' and search_condition_vc like '%NOT NULL';
```

Code to disable and enable constraint:

```
alter table  scott.my_table modify constraint SYS_C0019940 DISable;
alter table  scott.my_table modify constraint SYS_C0019940 ENable;
```